# Is $http.jsonp is blocking call.?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service, angularjs-http

As mentioned in the title I am using `$http.jsonp` in my application for client to server communication, when my application bootstraps it sends the request to server using `$http.jsonp` I am able to see in the network flow in the chrome development tool that when the `$http.jsonp` is called it leads to stop all other requests like image download etc and when I am making call to server I am able to see the ui transition are not smoother.

So is this is the problem with my implementation or is there is any way to run the remote service call in background.?

Comment: Every angularjs `$http` call is *asyncronous* and _should not_ be blocking. Can you provide a code snippet please?

Comment: Is jsonp request working? Issue is not clear at all

Answer (score 0):

It is not blocking.  It should execute a callback once the data is returned:

It should look like this:

```
 $http.jsonp('yourUrl')
    .success(function(data){
        console.log(data.found);
    });
```

If it looks like the above request and still doesn't work, you have something else blocking your call.